# In NSUserDefaults getting allKeysForObject array in unsorted manner

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, sorting

I stored object in `NSUserDefaults` with key name after that I stored same object with different key name.
Then I want all key names of that object which I stored so I used the API of `allKeysForObject` and I got array but its not in sorted manner, so please help me to get sorted array of keys.

Comment: Then you have to sort it by yourself.

Comment: You have to sort it by yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the way which will help you to achieve this is:

1. Store value with timestamp related to key in user default.
2. So the good way is to Store & Retrive custom object in user default.
   https://github.com/roomorama/RMMapper
3. Your custom object will have a property for timestamp also.
4. And after Fetching values from user default just sort array using the
   timestamp property.

Answer (score 1):

The possible way is to put all the keys into an `NSArray` and retrieve the objects related to the corresponding keys using `NSUserDefaults` and put the values into another `NSArray` which would give you the values in the required order.